# How to include an XHTML page in another XHTML without overriding the CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jsf, primefaces

I need to include an XHTML file (file1) inside another XHTML file (file2). file1 is using primefaces components and styles. file2 is a bootstrap template which uses bootstrap styling and css. When I include file1 inside file2, primefaces styles are overridden by bootstrap, and as a result some primefaces components don't work properly.

How do I include file1 in file2 without causing its CSS to be overridden?

Answer (score 2):

HTML already doesn't support this in first place, so JSF/Facelets as being just a HTML output generator can do little for you.

You've basically two options:

1. Alter Bootstrap CSS selectors to be prefixed with a strong and specific selector which is in your web application guaranteed to be used only to wrap Bootstrap templates. You could if necessary do this programmatically during serving the Bootstrap CSS file as JSF resource.
2. Inclue one of the template files via an `<iframe>`. This will however not share the JSF view state with the parent template. So you may still run into trouble if you have any JSF forms in there.